# git: list remote changes

Tags: git, revision-history, fast-forward

I have a git remote "mine" (happens to be a github fork) that has managed to get ahead by 2 commits. My local master branch is ahead of it by 244 commits (pulled from the original gitub repo). As a result, pushing to "mine" is not fast-forward.

How can I list the 2 commits by which "mine" is ahead?

Comment: This question gets asked a lot on Stack Overflow, when I find a good canonical answer, I'll come back and mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Cupcake I know. I looked for the answer too, but only found various ways of addressing a 'non fast-forward' push attempt, not how to diagnose what's blocking it. Please do mark as a duplicate if you find one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you want to list the commits on the remote branch that don't exist in your local branch yet. This is simply accomplished using a commit range `..`:

```bash
# Get the most recent updates from the remote
git fetch <remote>

# List all commits that are in <remote>/<branch> but not in your local <branch>
git log --oneline <branch>..<remote>/<branch>
```

### Documentation

From the [official Linux Kernel `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html):

> ```
> <since>..<until>
> ```
>
> Show only commits between the named two commits. When either `<since>` or `<until>` is omitted, it defaults to HEAD, i.e. the tip of the current branch. For a more complete list of ways to spell `<since>` and `<until>`, see [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

### See Also

- [Pro Git § 6.1 Git Tools - Revision Selection - Commit Ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges)