# git pull command to just show list of files to sync, but should not sync

Tags: git, pull

Like how we use -n switch in 'p4 sync -n' in Perforce to just show the files to sync and not actually sync, Is there a switch that can be passed in 'git' command as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: list remote changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24182162/git-list-remote-changes)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
git fetch origin
git diff master origin/master --names-only
```

This will fetch the changes from your upstream but won't merge them to your local branch, and then you can check the differences between those two.